# How to update workflow with active process instances in JBPM 6.2

Tags: java, jbpm

We've developed an app leveraging JBPM that's now running live. In our development process when we needed to update the workflow we typically killed active process instances in order to run a new build.

However, now that the app is running live we need to update the workflow without killing process instances. Since starting to work with JBPM we've found documentation on how to do these types of things sparse. So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction of a protocol to carry this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the migration project developed by one of the core jBPM engineers
http://mswiderski.blogspot.cz/2014/11/process-instance-migration-made-easy.html

It's a standard KJAR including set of processes, which have couple of tasks, which guides you throughout the migration.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help.